# I am creating a wordpress widget (Contact Us form). I want to send the form data in database

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my HTML part:

```
<input type="text" name="wd-name" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="send" />
```

Here is the php part:

```
function db_connect(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "test"; //'test' is table name

if( $_POST["send"] != '' && $_POST["wd-name"] != ''){
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix ."test";
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['wd-name'], '');
    $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
                array(
                    'name' => $name
                )
            );
   }
}

if( isset($_POST['send']) ) db_connect();
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_connect');
```

on click the submit button nothing is happening..it just going to top of the page. I searched all the important links but nothing found. What thing am I missing?

Comment: What URL is your form sending the data to? Have you set up any kind of routing, so that this particular request would trigger your function?

Comment: no kind of url am using....@CBroe. i just want to send it to my 'phpmyadmin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description :**
Contact form have 4 things Name,email,Message,subject all are required field here.You can modify as per you requirement.You can use this code,write in plugin and place inside plugin folder.

**For print frontend form**

```
function html_form_code() {
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Name (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Subject (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Message (required) <br/>';
    echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

**For Backend Send email to admin**

```
function deliver_mail() {

    // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

        // sanitize form values
        $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
        $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

        // get the blog administrator's email address
        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contact will get back to you very soon.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }
}
```

**Genrate Shortcode Its easy where you want to print**

```
function contactform_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    deliver_mail();
    html_form_code();

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'my_contact_form', 'contactf_shortcode' );
```

?>

Comment: Thanks for your response. i was seeking somebody will help in these days. i will check your code @vasim....But i solved the problem through my own.

Comment: you are welcome.Its better way to create plugin using code so that you can easily include and exclude your code.(enable / disable hook and filter)

Answer (score 0):

By what you've shown in your html, it seems you didn't declare proper tags for Form. Define action as to what your form will do on submit. Your HTML code needs some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah i got the solution now.....

instead of lines:

```
$wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
            array(
                'name' => $name
            )
        );
////Code...
if( isset($_POST['send']) ) db_connect();
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_connect');
```

I wrote:

```
$wpdb->insert(
        'test',
            array(
                'name' => $name
            )
        );
add_shortcode('shortcode_name', 'db_connect');
```